# Кастомизация slick-slider. Нужно сделать, чтобы слайды наезжали друг на друга

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slick.js

Нужно добиться такого эффекта, чтобы каждый следующий слайд немного наезжал на предыдущий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент реализовано таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код на css, реализующий вертикальный сдвиг:

```
.slick-slide:nth-child(4n + 1){
    .surf-box{
        margin-top: 32px;
    }
}
.slick-slide:nth-child(4n + 3){
    .surf-box{
        margin-top: 89px;
    }
}
```

"surf-box" как можно заметить - это обертка каждого каждого слайда внутри слика. Его код в html:

```
<div class="surf-box">
      <div class="surf-box__wrapper" style="background-image: url(images/slide-1.jpg);">
        <div class="surf-box__inner">
          <div class="surf-box__inner-title">Malibu Beach</div>
          <div class="surf-box__inner-location">California <span>|</span> USA</div>
          <div class="surf-box__inner-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn">
              view <span>surf</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

И таких 8 слайдов. На странице отображаются 4.

Код в js

```
$('.surf-slider').slick({
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 1,
prevArrow: '<img class="slider-arrows slider-arrows__left" src="images/arrows-left.svg" alt="">',
nextArrow: '<img class="slider-arrows slider-arrows__right" src="images/arrows-right.svg" alt="">',
});
```

Я пробовал сделать вот так:

```
.surf-box{
    position: relative;
}
.slick-slide:nth-child(2n + 2){
    .surf-box{
        margin-left: -40px;
    }
}
```

и получил такой эффект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, это не то, что нужно :(

Покопался в настройках слика в документахе - готовых настроек под это не увидел.. Хелп, гайз!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Оказывается все очень просто.
Для этого использовал лишь 1 доп строчку css кода в блок-контейнер слайдов "surf-box":

```
.surf-box{
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 40px) !important;
}
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно написать только это и будет работать:

```
.slick-track {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.surf-box {
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]